# Installing php plugin in Sonar Qube

Tags: php, sonarqube

I am trying to install to php plugin in SonarQube. I have downloaded the  latest versions. 
I followed the steps mentioned here 
[SonarQube Installing a Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+a+Plugin)

From the Update Center
-> Available Plugins I selelcted php and clicked install. And I got the message "SonarQube needs to be restarted in order to install 1 plugins". After that I restarted SonarQube server. But I can't see Php plugin under Installed plugins. I found that the php plugin jar file has been been downloaded to /sonar/extensions/downloads/ folder but its not installed. I moved this file manually to /sonar/extensions/plugins and restarted the SonarQube server. But still its not showing as installed. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your jar file is corrupted. Try to remove it and download again.